# React.js library that does same thing as react-native-router-flux for React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm relatively new to react.js & react-native and was wondering if there is a react.js library that works the same way as react-native's 'react-native-router-flux'.

For example, the following code block which I have on my signup page [React-Native]:

```
  toLogInPage() {
     Actions.login()
  }
```

works very easily with the code from my routes page [React-Native]:

```
<Router>
    <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"  initial={true} />
</Router>
```

Does react.js have something similar? I see a 'react-router-flux' library with an {Action} component. Does this do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You just haven't asked the internet, But there you go : https://reacttraining.com/react-router